# Android Adview not found

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, adview

SOLVED: see comments how error was fixed. This is a very common problem this topic will fix errors. To prove solution works see ads working in my free app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.colour.colourguessfree

Before I get started, I know this is a common problem I have spent the evening on stackoverflow looking at the similar topic with no avail.

I am having great trouble with admob and displaying adview. On my app when it loads where the adview is the message inside states: Required XML attribute"adSize" was missing. I have tried numerous approaches to try and fix this so I feel the best way is to show what I have an hope someone can point me in the right direction.

manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.colourguessfree"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

         <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="14"
            android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <application

            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <activity android:name=".gameover" android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            </activity> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
         </application>
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="************"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
```

WorkPlace:
[image]

Properties:
[image] 
Build Path:
[image]

### Help with this is most welcomed, I've tried so many fixes. a clear guide would be great!

UPDATE:

This is another method i've tried from the Google Play Services Migration. The xml code i've tried is:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

with java code in the oncreate as:

```
AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID")
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

But this gives an error in the adview says missing adactivity with android.configchanges in androidmanifest.xml

UPDATE 2

Im so tottally lost not sure if it is working, the log seems to be pointing at it half work main issue is I can't see the ads at all.

LOG:

```
10-02 23:26:42.088: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5260): Google Play services is missing.
10-02 23:26:42.118: I/Ads(5260): Starting ad request.
10-02 23:26:42.158: I/Ads(5260): Please set theme of AdActivity to @android:style/Theme.Translucent to enable transparent background interstitial ad.
10-02 23:26:42.178: D/WebSettings(5260): mDataPath: /data/data/com.example.colourguessfree
10-02 23:26:42.208: D/WebSettings(5260): mDataPath: /data/data/com.example.colourguessfree
10-02 23:26:42.378: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(5260): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-02 23:26:42.388: D/memalloc(5260): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5228d000 size:3686400 offset:3072000 fd:82
10-02 23:26:42.588: D/memalloc(5260): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x528d9000 size:7405568 offset:6791168 fd:85
10-02 23:26:43.178: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5260): Google Play services is missing.
10-02 23:26:43.178: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5260): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 1
10-02 23:26:43.208: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5260): Google Play services is missing.
10-02 23:26:43.208: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5260): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 1
10-02 23:26:43.238: W/dalvikvm(5260): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 640: Landroid/net/ConnectivityManager;.isActiveNetworkMetered ()Z
10-02 23:26:43.288: D/WebSettings(5260): mDataPath: /data/data/com.example.colourguessfree
10-02 23:26:43.328: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/host_resolver_helper/host_resolver_helper.cc:66: [1002/232643:INFO:host_resolver_helper.cc(66)] DNSPreResolver::Init got hostprovider:0x4cb15230
10-02 23:26:43.328: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/base/host_resolver_impl.cc:1515: [1002/232643:INFO:host_resolver_impl.cc(1515)] HostResolverImpl::SetPreresolver preresolver:0x01aeba08
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/(5260): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc: libtcpfinaggr.so successfully loaded
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/(5260): external/chromium/net/socket/tcp_fin_aggregation_factory.cc,: TCP Fin Aggregation initializing method was found in libtcpfinaggr.so
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/TCPFinAggregation(5260): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation was set
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/TCPFinAggregation(5260): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.wait was set, value: 20
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/TCPFinAggregation(5260): system property net.tcp.fin.aggregation.close was set, value: 300
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/TCPFinAggregation(5260): system property net.close.unused.sockets was set, value: 1
10-02 23:26:43.328: D/TCPFinAggregation(5260): Failed to get network status! received ret: -2
10-02 23:26:43.338: V/WebRequest(5260): WebRequest::WebRequest, setPriority = 1
10-02 23:26:43.348: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:52: [1002/232643:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(52)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin initializing...
10-02 23:26:43.348: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:57: [1002/232643:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(57)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin lib loaded
10-02 23:26:43.348: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/hostres_plugin_bridge.cc:63: [1002/232643:INFO:hostres_plugin_bridge.cc(63)] StatHubCreateHostResPlugin plugin connected
10-02 23:26:43.348: V/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/http/http_cache.cc:1173: [1002/232643:INFO:http_cache.cc(1173)] HttpCache::OnBackendCreated HostStat created
10-02 23:26:43.348: E/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [1002/232643:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.example.colourguessfree isn't supported.
10-02 23:26:43.348: E/chromium(5260): external/chromium/net/disk_cache/stat_hub.cc:190: [1002/232643:ERROR:stat_hub.cc(190)] StatHub::Init - App com.example.colourguessfree isn't supported.
10-02 23:26:43.498: W/Ads(5260): AdWebView unable to handle URL: http://192.168.1.254/mobile-step0.html?org_url=http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net%2fmads%2fstatic%2fmad%2fsdk%2fnative%2fsdk%2dcore%2dv40%2ehtml
10-02 23:26:43.578: E/Ads(5260): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined (null:1)
10-02 23:26:43.578: E/Web Console(5260): Uncaught ReferenceError: AFMA_buildAdURL is not defined at null:1
```

The google documentation is so annoying it so often refers to the old method they no longer support....

Comment: i can't see any mention of the fix. but i can see that your router is stealing the url and redirecting you to something else: `10-02 23:26:43.498: W/Ads(5260): AdWebView unable to handle URL: http://192.168.1.254/mobile-step0.html?org_url=http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net%2fmads%2fstatic%2fmad%2fsdk%2fnative%2fsdk%2dcore%2dv40%2ehtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing:

```
 xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

to

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

check out this tutorial from Google : [Google Play Services Migration](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration)

Comment: try downloading API 19 and try again there are a lot of problems with the 4.4 Wearable API

Comment: since you dont have Google Play Service on Device check out this link : http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/google-play-services-setup.html it will download Google Services when needed. plus in the Manifest add to the Activity of Ads the Theme the Error requst by android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

Answer (score 0):

I have currently quite a **mix of legacy admob code with google play admob** code.

Besides the already mentioned `xmlns:ads` that you should change to `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` you also have to:

---

change this in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

to:

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

---

remove this attribute in the xml layout of your adview, because it is no longer supported and load ads programmatically instead:

```
 ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
```

---

read the guide [Google Play Services Migration](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration) and make sure that everything in your code looks like described in the **right column**

Comment: Then try running your app in an emulator or connected device and lock at the logcat output (not console). Admob usually logs the reason why it is not showing up.